# What is the best charging practice for my bike light's lithium ion battery?

Tags: headlights

I have a Light and Motion Seca 700 with a Lithium Ion battery.  It has a multi-chem smart charger.  I have heard that some batteries like NiMH have "memory" and should be mostly drained before recharging, while a LiIon battery is not supposed to have "memory."  How should I charge the battery to insure a long run time and battery life?

Answer (score 7):

You should fully charge the battery after every use.

Ignore outdated concerns about early NiCad batteries that exhibited a '[memory effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel-cadmium_battery#Memory_and_lazy_battery_effects)' when discharged repeatedly to the same Depth of Discharge (DOD)/ State of Charge ([SOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_charge)).

Almost all secondary (rechargeable) batteries will benefit from regular, complete charging.  The less you discharge a battery, the more total lifetime capacity you will get from it.

That is, If you take the same battery and regularly use 25% of it's capacity then charge it, you will get C Wh of capacity out of it over its lifetime.  If you do the same, but use 95% of its capacity, you may find you only get 0.5C Wh over its lifetime.

Regarding Lithium batteries generally, it is *extremely* important to use the correct [charger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_polymer_battery#Charging) for the battery, or the correct mode on a multi-chemistry charger.  Otherwise there may be a fire...